# Android handle 'search' button press on custom keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I'am developing my own custom keyboard.

How to handle 'search' button press in case if our keyboard opened with `IME_ACTION_SEARCH` parameter?

I have following code, but unfortunately in search case it's not working. In regular situation with Done button it working good.

```
        final int options = this.getCurrentInputEditorInfo().imeOptions;
        final int actionId = options & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;

        switch (actionId) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH));
                break;
            default:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to do it:

```
endDefaultEditorAction(true);
```

it's a method of `InputMethodService`

The full code is:

```
    case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        final int options = this.getCurrentInputEditorInfo().imeOptions;
        final int actionId = options & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;

        switch (actionId) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                sendDefaultEditorAction(true);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                sendDefaultEditorAction(true);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                sendDefaultEditorAction(true);
                break;
            default:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        }

        break;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! But why send the event manually doesn't work? Do you've any idea?

Comment: @Andrey options & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION what does this & operator means here?